# Twitter REST API missing geo-tagged tweets from Europe

Tags: api, rest, geotag, crowdsourcing, twitter

I used twitter's REST API to get few thousands tweets from last two days. Everything went ok, but when I put tweets on the map, there is empty "box-like" area (no tweets for almost entire Europe - look at 1st picture).

Last week I used REST API to get data from around India and everything were ok (look at 2nd picture).

I used GET search/tweets with geocode parameter:

"
*Returns tweets by users located within a given radius of the given latitude/longitude. The location is preferentially taking from the Geotagging API, but will fall back to their Twitter profile. The parameter value is specified by “latitude,longitude,radius”, where radius units must be specified as either “mi” (miles) or “km” (kilometers). Note that you cannot use the near operator via the API to geocode arbitrary locations; however you can use this geocode parameter to search near geocodes directly. A maximum of 1,000 distinct “sub-regions” will be considered when using the radius modifier.*

**Example Values: 37.781157,-122.398720,1mi**
"

More at: https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/search/tweets

Anyone seen this problem? Any clue?

In my case I used central point around like this "20.0,50.0,2500mi"

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks like you've exceeded the maximum number returned. Try a series of smaller areas

Comment: In case I exceed some limit, I think twitter will close my connection, but my is still running without any problem. Everything is set up to not go after limit. And if it is limit problem, I dont get why there are empty "boxes" over some areas and not just less count of tweets in the whole area... But thanks for reply.

Comment: how many points are in each of those maps?

Comment: Your better off doing this by country https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/search (bottom)

Comment: First map (Europe) "only" ~ 10 000 points (I was checking data after first few hours of collecting it). Second map is after almost 1 week of collection - there are ~ 1 150 000 points

Comment: I already tried requests for smaller area (circle 1500mi point), but it didn't help. 2nd map is for circle 2000mi. When I will get too many small areas I will have trouble with joining data again and I will need to store some duplicate data... I had problem with limit on stream API only so I switched to rest api when I saw everything works fine (like in 2nd map). Thanks for your time.

Comment: I find it suspicious / interesting that the Greenwich meridian appears to form the left edge of the bottom image, and the left-edge of the 'hole' in your first image. It may not be related to your problem, though, but it could be worth investigating.

Comment: I dont think it is Europe per say, rather there appear to be three smaller square tiles covering Europe and Turkey. That means it is unlikely to be some consistent problem with how the query was written. My first reaction is that this is probably how twitter tiles its own databases and for some reason the link was interrupted / not called for those three tiles.

Comment: yes, I also thing that maybe the "tiles" are some twitter servers, which maybe have some different rules/limits for responding (maybe just to some kind of requests - maybe by relation to center of requsted area?) and they just ignores my requests... but weird is that few days before (2nd picture - request centered to Saudi Arabia) everything was ok..